# com.sun.jna.Pointer cannot be cast to com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinDef.LPARAM

Tags: java, jna

Error:

> error:com.sun.jna.Pointer connot be cast to com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinDef.LPARAM
>   error location:return User32.INSTANCE.CallNextHookEx(hHook, nCode, wParam,
>                               keyInfo.getPointer());

Code:

```
HMODULE hMod = Kernel32.INSTANCE.GetModuleHandle(null);

HOOKPROC lpfn = new LowLevelKeyboardProc()
{
    int count = 1;

    public LRESULT callback(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT keyInfo)
    {
        System.out.println("nCode =" + nCode + ", wParam =" + wParam 
            + ", vkCode=" + keyInfo.vkCode);
        count++;

        if (count > 100)
        {
            quit = true;
        }

        return User32.INSTANCE.CallNextHookEx(hHook, nCode, wParam, keyInfo.getPointer());
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to manually construct the `LPARAM` from the pointer's value as seen in the JNA [KeyHook example](https://github.com/java-native-access/jna/blob/f99b613a1b09fe4e6f249d09650d652dd3b0075e/contrib/w32keyhook/com/sun/jna/contrib/demo/KeyHook.java#L45).

```
Pointer ptr = keyInfo.getPointer();
long peer = Pointer.nativeValue(ptr);
return User32.INSTANCE.CallNextHookEx(hHook, nCode, wParam, new LParam(peer));
```